# ¿Por qué los jtextfield envían datos vacios a mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, netbeans-8.2, jtextfield

Tengo un proyecto enviando datos a mysql, la conexión esta todo perfecto, pero al llenar y enviar el formulario en mysql aparecen como datos vacíos.

```
Login lg = new Login();
    RegistroAdmin ra = new RegistroAdmin();
    PreparedStatement ps;

public int Resgistrar(){

        LimpiarReg();

        int resultado=0;

        ConexionMySql sql = new ConexionMySql();
        Connection conn = null;

        try{

        conn = sql.conectarMySQL();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO usuarios (nickName,clave,nom_usuario,apellidos,telefono,correo,direccion) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, ra.txtNick.getText());
        ps.setString(2, ra.txtClave.getText());
        ps.setString(3, ra.txtNombre.getText());
        ps.setString(4, ra.txtApellido.getText());
        ps.setString(5, ra.txtTel.getText());
        ps.setString(6, ra.txtCorreo.getText());
        ps.setString(7, ra.txtDir.getText());
        resultado = ps.executeUpdate();

        if(resultado>0){
            resultado=1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empleado registrado correctamente");
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error de conexión", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

He ocupado este método para "limpiar" los jtextfield, pero aunque llene el formulario se siguen enviando datos vacíos.

```
public void LimpiarReg(){

        ra.txtNombre.setText("");
        ra.txtApellido.setText("");
        ra.txtTel.setText("");
        ra.txtCorreo.setText("");
        ra.txtDir.setText("");
        ra.txtNick.setText("");
        ra.txtClave.setText("");
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el botón para enviar simplemente llamo al método.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que le asignas valores a tu objeto `ra` antes de pasarlo al `prepareStatement`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola Germán!, El flujo de ejecución en Java es lineal por lo que va a ejecutarse cada linea de código en el orden escrito.

```
public int Resgistrar(){

    LimpiarReg(); //<--- Este método limpia los campos

    int resultado=0;

    ConexionMySql sql = new ConexionMySql();
    Connection conn = null;
    //...
    //Para cuando llega a esta parte el valor ya se vació
    ps.setString(1, ra.txtNick.getText());
```

Entonces si necesitas que se limpien los registros deberías hacerlo después de usar los datos, no antes.

```
    //LimpiarReg(); <--- Lo cortas
    int resultado=0;

    ConexionMySql sql = new ConexionMySql();
    Connection conn = null;

    try{

    conn = sql.conectarMySQL();
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO usuarios (nickName,clave,nom_usuario,apellidos,telefono,correo,direccion) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, ra.txtNick.getText());
    ps.setString(2, ra.txtClave.getText());
    ps.setString(3, ra.txtNombre.getText());
    ps.setString(4, ra.txtApellido.getText());
    ps.setString(5, ra.txtTel.getText());
    ps.setString(6, ra.txtCorreo.getText());
    ps.setString(7, ra.txtDir.getText());
    resultado = ps.executeUpdate();

    LimpiarReg();// <--- Con ponerlo aquí basta.
```

Comment: +1 gracias bro no me habia percatado